# Is it possible to get the value of an item populated by xsl?

Tags: javascript, xml, flash, xslt

I'm working with a Flash map that has an XML file.  I've populated a list on the map's webpage (outside the flash map) from an XML using XSLT.  I want to add a JS function to this through the XSL that selects the (populated) element from the XML that will interact with the map.

For example, my list is the 50 states.  Here is a small part from the XML:

```
<attributes>
        <col name="State">Kentucky</col>
        <STATENAME>Kentucky</STATENAME>
  </attributes>
```

Etc... all 50 states are included in the XML as above

Here is how I populated the list:

```
<table border="0">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="map/layer/feature/attributes">
<xsl:sort select="STATENAME"/>
      <tr>
        <td><a onMouseOver='highlight()' onMouseOut='highlight_clear()'><xsl:attribute name="href">http://mysite.com/<xsl:value-of select="STATENAME"/>.html</xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="STATENAME" /></a></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
```

All 50 states come up this way with a link to their individual page: http://mysite.com/statename.html

Here is the Javascript:

```
function highlight() {
            theMap.features('State="Kentucky"').highlight({visible: true, fillColor: "#FFFF00", fillAlpha: 1.0});          
        }
```

The key here is **('State="Kentucky"')** I am trying to get State to = the SAME state that is populated in the list without having to write 50 different functions - one for each state.  For example, when all 50 states are populated, if the mouse goes over Texas, it would automatically bring up theMap.features('State="Texas"') if it goes over Nebraska, then it would bring up Nebraska.

I tried doing this:

```
function highlight() {
var sn='<xsl:value-of select="STATENAME"/>';
                theMap.features('State="sn"').highlight({visible: true, fillColor: "#FFFF00", fillAlpha: 1.0}); }
```

but it did not work, nor did I think it would.  But, it is essentially the idea of what I would like to happen.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
     <th>State</th>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="map/layer/feature/attributes/STATENAME">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a onMouseOver='highlight("{.}")' 
             onMouseOut='highlight_clear()'
             href='http://mysite.com/{.}.html'>
             <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Then just change your highlight() function to this:

```
function highlight(state) {
    theMap.features('State="' + state + '"')
          .highlight({visible: true, 
                      fillColor: "#FFFF00", 
                      fillAlpha: 1.0});          
}
```